# "Apollonius theorem": how do I prove it?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

[image]

The curve in the picture is an ellipse with foci $A,B$ and center $C$. $P,Q$ lie on the ellipse. The line through $P$ is tangent to the ellipse and parallel to $VQ$ and $CD$. Thus, $CP$ and $CD$ are conjugate diameters. I have been told the following.

> **Apollonius's theorem**
>
> $$\frac{VP\cdot GV}{QV^2}=\frac{CP^2}{CD^2}.$$

I tried proving it and failed, I googled and found [this completely unrelated theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem), I tried again and all I managed to do was to prove that the following implies my theorem:

$$CQ'\cdot CP'=CD^2.$$

To this end, note that $PQV\sim PP'C$ and $GQV\sim GQ'C$, because of sides lying on the same line or parallel lines. Hence:

$$\frac{VP}{QV}=\frac{CP}{CP'},\qquad\frac{GV}{QV}=\frac{CG}{CQ'}=\frac{CP}{CQ'},$$

hence, by substitution:

$$\frac{VP\cdot GV}{QV^2}=\frac{CP^2}{CD^2}\iff\frac{CP^2}{CP'\cdot CQ'}=\frac{CP^2}{CD^2}\iff CD^2=CP'\cdot CQ'.$$

And now I'm entirely stuck. I already tried describing this ellipse as $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and thus parametrizing it as $\gamma(t)=(a\cos t,b\sin t)$, and finding all the relevant points, except the calculations got so horrible even Wolfram wouldn't compute, so I stopped. I tried constructing parallelograms to view both sides of these equations as areas or ratios of areas, but I can't see any way to go from there. So I'm completely stuck. How do I conclude?

**Note**

For the record, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt((tan((s%2Bt)%2F2)*(a+sin+t-cot+t)%2Ba+cos+t)%5E2%2B(tan((s%2Bt)%2F2)*(-b+cos+t%2Bb%2Fa+*+cot%5E2t)-b+cot+t+cos+t)%5E2)) is $CP'$, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt((cot((s%2Bt)%2F2)*(a+sin+t%2Bcot+t)-a+cos+t)%5E2%2B(cot((s%2Bt)%2F2)*(-b+cos+t-b%2Fa+*+cot%5E2t)%2Bb+cot+t+cos+t)%5E2)) should be $CQ'$, and luckily $CD^2$ is just $a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t$. Try multiplying those two roots…

Comment: I'm confused. $VG=GV$?

Comment: @Arnaldo typo. Fixed.

Comment: see here: http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/intersecting-chord-theorem-ellipses

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento please consider converting that to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @ArnaldoNascimento posted a link as a comment and the link answered the question, but did not convert it to a comment, I am doing so to get this off the unanswered list. However, I don't have time to copy the proof here, so I will sum-up the preliminary lemma, and put in an image of the proof of the desired result. If anybody has time, by all means I encourage them to copy it into the post.

The proof of this theorem resides at [this link](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/intersecting-chord-theorem-ellipses).

One first proves $CV\cdot CT=CP^2$, where $T$ is obtained by intersecting the tangent at $Q$ with the line containing $C,P,V$. Such a statement is easy in the case of a circle, where it is obtained by Euclid plus $CP=CQ$, and can be generalized to ellipses by dilating the ellipse figure into a circle figure, where the statement holds, and observing that proportions between segments on a single line are preserved.

Then, with [a bunch of proportions and a couple extra points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODU4q.png), one proves the desired result. Image:

[image]